# Calculate a grouped median in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When using pyspark, I'd like to be able to calculate the difference between grouped values and their median for the group.  Is this possible?  Here is some code I hacked up that does what I want except that it calculates the grouped diff from mean.  Also, please feel free to comment on how I could make this better if you feel like being helpful :)

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import (
    StringType,
    LongType,
    DoubleType,
    StructField,
    StructType
)
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


sc = SparkContext(appName='myapp')
spark = SparkSession(sc)

file_name = 'data.csv'

fields = [
    StructField(
        'group2',
        LongType(),
        True),
    StructField(
        'name',
        StringType(),
        True),
    StructField(
        'value',
        DoubleType(),
        True),
    StructField(
        'group1',
        LongType(),
        True)
]
schema = StructType(fields)

df = spark.read.csv(
    file_name, header=False, mode="DROPMALFORMED", schema=schema
)
df.show()
means = df.select([
    'group1',
    'group2',
    'name',
    'value']).groupBy([
        'group1',
        'group2'
    ]).agg(
        F.mean('value').alias('mean_value')
    ).orderBy('group1', 'group2')

cond = [df.group1 == means.group1, df.group2 == means.group2]

means.show()
df = df.select([
    'group1',
    'group2',
    'name',
    'value']).join(
        means,
        cond
    ).drop(
        df.group1
    ).drop(
        df.group2
    ).select('group1',
             'group2',
             'name',
             'value',
             'mean_value')

final = df.withColumn(
    'diff',
    F.abs(df.value - df.mean_value))
final.show()

sc.stop()
```

And here is an example dataset I'm playing with:

```
100,name1,0.43,0
100,name2,0.33,0
100,name3,0.73,0
101,name1,0.29,0
101,name2,0.96,0
101,name3,0.42,0
102,name1,0.01,0
102,name2,0.42,0
102,name3,0.51,0
103,name1,0.55,0
103,name2,0.45,0
103,name3,0.02,0
104,name1,0.93,0
104,name2,0.16,0
104,name3,0.74,0
105,name1,0.41,0
105,name2,0.65,0
105,name3,0.29,0
100,name1,0.51,1
100,name2,0.51,1
100,name3,0.43,1
101,name1,0.59,1
101,name2,0.55,1
101,name3,0.84,1
102,name1,0.01,1
102,name2,0.98,1
102,name3,0.44,1
103,name1,0.47,1
103,name2,0.16,1
103,name3,0.02,1
104,name1,0.83,1
104,name2,0.89,1
104,name3,0.31,1
105,name1,0.59,1
105,name2,0.77,1
105,name3,0.45,1
```

and here is what I'm trying to produce:

```
group1,group2,name,value,median,diff
0,100,name1,0.43,0.43,0.0
0,100,name2,0.33,0.43,0.10
0,100,name3,0.73,0.43,0.30
0,101,name1,0.29,0.42,0.13
0,101,name2,0.96,0.42,0.54
0,101,name3,0.42,0.42,0.0
0,102,name1,0.01,0.42,0.41
0,102,name2,0.42,0.42,0.0
0,102,name3,0.51,0.42,0.09
0,103,name1,0.55,0.45,0.10
0,103,name2,0.45,0.45,0.0
0,103,name3,0.02,0.45,0.43
0,104,name1,0.93,0.74,0.19
0,104,name2,0.16,0.74,0.58
0,104,name3,0.74,0.74,0.0
0,105,name1,0.41,0.41,0.0
0,105,name2,0.65,0.41,0.24
0,105,name3,0.29,0.41,0.24
1,100,name1,0.51,0.51,0.0
1,100,name2,0.51,0.51,0.0
1,100,name3,0.43,0.51,0.08
1,101,name1,0.59,0.59,0.0
1,101,name2,0.55,0.59,0.04
1,101,name3,0.84,0.59,0.25
1,102,name1,0.01,0.44,0.43
1,102,name2,0.98,0.44,0.54
1,102,name3,0.44,0.44,0.0
1,103,name1,0.47,0.16,0.31
1,103,name2,0.16,0.16,0.0
1,103,name3,0.02,0.16,0.14
1,104,name1,0.83,0.83,0.0
1,104,name2,0.89,0.83,0.06
1,104,name3,0.31,0.83,0.52
1,105,name1,0.59,0.59,0.0
1,105,name2,0.77,0.59,0.18
1,105,name3,0.45,0.59,0.14
```

Comment: I'm trying to use `window` function. However, I still haven't achieved the task with my created `udf` median function

Comment: My understanding is to do this right, you need a udaf function since this would be implemented in .agg(...) but udaf is not available in python.

Comment: yeah, that's right @craigching. i just updated my attempt to do mean aggregation. however, it's not the right solution that you asked for yet.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can solve it using udf function `median` to it.First let's create simple example given above.

```python
# example data
ls = [[100,'name1',0.43,0],
      [100,'name2',0.33,0],
      [100,'name3',0.73,0],
      [101,'name1',0.29,0],
      [101,'name2',0.96,0],
      [...]]
df = spark.createDataFrame(ls, schema=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

Here is the `udf` function for calculating median

```python
# udf for median
import numpy as np
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

def median(values_list):
    med = np.median(values_list)
    return float(med)
udf_median = func.udf(median, FloatType())

group_df = df.groupby(['a', 'd'])
df_grouped = group_df.agg(udf_median(func.collect_list(col('c'))).alias('median'))
df_grouped.show()
```

Finally, you can join it back with original `df` on in order to get median column back.

```python
df_grouped = df_grouped.withColumnRenamed('a', 'a_').withColumnRenamed('d', 'd_')
df_final = df.join(df_grouped, [df.a == df_grouped.a_, df.d == df_grouped.d_]).select('a', 'b', 'c', 'median')
df_final = df_final.withColumn('diff', func.round(func.col('c') - func.col('median'), scale=2))
```

note that I use `round` at the end to prevent extra digits that come up after median operation.

Comment: your udf median works for me.  are there any caveats to what you're doing there?

Comment: @craigching, yeah, it works. it just won't give the right solution on what you need yet. you have to join it back with `('a', 'b', 'd')` in order to finish the task.

Comment: if you want to clean that up, remove the first part and just keep the median part, I'm willing to mark this answered as it's exactly what I asked and is working for me. Although I suppose the windowing would be really neat to implement if you have it.

Comment: hi @craigching, i cleaned up the solution. hope this works for you!

Comment: I'll accept it, but could you clean it up just a bit more please?  your "col" need to be "func.col" and your example data doesn't match.  Nevertheless, it works and I will accept it.

Comment: in case you want to compute the median without any udf, you can look at the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63374881/2265478