# calculate median values with even number of rows in pyspark

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, median

I am using this formula taken from another SO post to calculate the median values of columns in pyspark:

```
columns = ['id', 'dogs', 'cats']
vals = [(1, 2, 0),(2, 0, 1)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(vals, columns)
df.approxQuantile(list(c for c in df.columns), [0.5], 0)
```

The formula works when there are an odd number of rows in the df but if the number of rows is even, it is not taking the mean between the central elements (I mean after sorting of course), but only the first one.

The result from the code above is for example:

```
[[1.0], [0.0], [0.0]]
```

while it should have been:

```
[[1.5], [1.0], [0.5]]
```

How to correct calculate the median value in pyspark?

Comment: Well a work around could be to first sort the `df` and then create a row number column and after this calculate the median .... thought it will be inefficient way ....

Comment: I think you're thinking in the average. Median will give you the number that is in the middle of a sorted distribution. It must be a number from the distribution. The implementation of  `approxQuantile` is the following: `floor((p - err) * N) <= rank(x) <= ceil((p + err) * N).`

Comment: No @pedvaljim, he/she is correct, when there are and even number of values, convention is to take the mean of the two middle vals after sorting

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hacky way to get the median

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2019)

def get_median(df, col):
    # if # df rows are even get the "middle" values and average
    num_rows = df.count()
    if num_rows%2==0:
        mid_pt = num_rows/2
        q1 = df.approxQuantile( col, [0.5], 0)
        q2 = df.approxQuantile( col, [(mid_pt+1)*1./num_rows], 0)
        return(np.mean(q1+q2).tolist())
    return(df.approxQuantile( col, [0.5], 0))

# now test it out
df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.rand(20,2), columns=['dogs', 'cats'])
df['id'] = list(range(20))

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df)
df.approxQuantile( "cats", [0.5], 0)
# [0.5783015865898744]
```

Answer (score 0):

I computed the exact median by group (without using numpy). You can easily adapt the approch by removing the Windows part.

- If first assign a row_number for each value (after ordered it) by group, and compute the number of row for each group.
- For group with pair number of rows, I kept the two middle rows
- For group with odd number of rows, I kept hte middle row
- Then I computed the mean of the rows kept precedently by group

---

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

columns = ['group1_col', 'group2_col', 'value_col']
vals = [['a', 'aa',  1],
       ['a', 'aa', 2], 
       ['b', 'aa', 2], 
       ['b', 'aa', 0], 
       ['c', 'aa', 0], 
       ['c', 'bb', 1],
       ['d', 'bb', 10],
       ['d', 'bb', 20],
       ['d', 'bb', 30],
       ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(vals, columns)

def compute_median(self, col, median_name, by_col=None):
  """ Method to be added to spark native DataFrame class """
  df_without_null = self.filter(F.col(col).isNotNull())
  
  window_spec = Window.partitionBy()
  if by_col is not None:
      window_spec = Window.partitionBy(by_col)
  window_spec_order = window_spec.orderBy(col)                                  

  df = (df_without_null
        .withColumn('row_number', F.row_number().over(window_spec_order))                     
        .withColumn('total_rows', F.count(F.lit(1)).over(window_spec))
        )

  row_to_keep = (
      df
      .filter((F.col('row_number') == F.ceil(F.col('total_rows') / 2))
                 | ((F.col('total_rows') % 2 == 0)
              & (F.col('row_number') == F.floor(F.col('total_rows') / 2) + 1)))
  )

  if by_col is None:
      return row_to_keep.select(F.mean(F.col(col)).alias(median_name))
  return row_to_keep.groupBy(by_col).agg(F.mean(F.col(col)).alias(median_name))

# Add method to DataFrame class
DataFrame.compute_median = compute_median

# med = df.compute_median("value_col", "global_median")
# med.collect()
# global_median
#      2.0

# med_group1 = df.compute_median("value_col", "median", 'group1_col')
# med_group1.collect()
# group1_col | median
#    a       | 1.5
#    b       | 1.0
#    c       | 0.5
#    d       | 20.0

# med_group2 = df.compute_median("value_col", "median", 'group2_col')
# med_group1.collect()
# group1_col | median
#    aa       | 1.5
#    bb       | 15.0
```

You can check that my filter condition is equivalent to this one (longer but maybe more easy to understand)

```
res = (df_rank_and_number_or_row
       .filter(
                ((F.col('total_rows') % 2 == 0)
                    & ((F.col('row_number') == F.ceil(F.col('total_rows') / 2))
                         | (F.col('row_number') == F.floor(F.col('total_rows') / 2) + 1))
                ) |
                (F.col('total_rows') % 2 != 0)
                  & ((F.col('row_number') == F.ceil(F.col('total_rows') / 2))
                )
               )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It takes the average of the numbers commong in the middle. It works for odd number of observations as well.

`(np.array(a1.approxQuantile(['id', 'dogs', 'cats'], [0.5], 0)) + np.array(a1.approxQuantile(['id', 'dogs', 'cats'], [0.51], 0)))/2`

> Output: array([[1.5],
> [1. ],
> [0.5]])

This also works:

`a1.select(((percentile_approx(a1.id, 0.5,100000) + percentile_approx(a1.id, 0.51,100000))*.5)`