# how to calculate the median for multiple columns in pysparK?

Tags: pyspark

How to extend the below function to calculate the median for both 'c' and 'd' from this post:
[Calculate a grouped median in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42961456/calculate-a-grouped-median-in-pyspark)

```
# udf for median
import numpy as np
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

def median(values_list):
    med = np.median(values_list)
    return float(med)
udf_median = func.udf(median, FloatType())

group_df = df.groupby(['a', 'd'])
df_grouped = group_df.agg(udf_median(func.collect_list(col('c'))).alias('median'))
df_grouped.show()
```

Comment: or if there is another way of doing it; just trying to calculate the median for more than 1 column in pyspark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the summary.

```
df.summary().filter("summary = '50%'")
```